# How to use *.o and *.d files?

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I ma trying to run examples using a library. In the documentation to the library it is written that I need to copy all the files into my directory and than type `make`. After that I need to go to the "Debug" folder and type `./lib_examples` to run the examples.

I performed this sequence. As a result I have a lot of `*.o` and `*.d` files in the "Debug" subdirectory. Among them there is `lib_examples.o` and `lib_examples.h` files. But there is no `lib_example` file that I am supposed to execute.

Does anybody know what was supposed to happen and where it went wrong. Should I do one more step to be able to use `*.o` and `*.d` files?

Comment: Yes, you need to link the object files to make an executable. Can you show us the relevant bits from your make file? Do you have a link step there?

Comment: The .d files are likely dependency-lists, a most handy feature you can utilize between gcc and make to detect changes in no only your source files but also included files (and included files of those files, etc). Not a runtime-file, but definitely a build-time file type. [Read more about it here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites)

Answer (score 9):

The ".o" files are likely intermediate files from which the actual executable program should have been created.

The ".d" files are likely internal state used by the makefile, only important if you are making changes to the source code and then rebuilding "incrementally".

If, after running `make`, you have only these files but not the executable file, then the most likely explanation is that `make` encountered an error in creating the executable. If that's the case, then the last few lines of output generated by `make` should tell you more.